# How do I create a small button with three dots on it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to create a small button with three dots on it, like we see everywhere in visual studio, in order to load the `FolderBrowserDialog`.  How best to create this button? Best I did was to get a 23x23 button with margin and padding set to 0, three dots for the text (only two appear) and auto-ellipses on (which makes a third dot appear). The button is still much larger than I'd like and the dots don't stand out very well.

Comment: How small do you want the button? Usually, I just use a normal button with "..." as the text. I think it ends up being about 24x24 pixels.

Comment: You should be able to create a Button and make sure you set appearance to FlatStyle the Text of course should be Button.Text = "..."

Comment: If you end up using a font don't forget to test how it looks with different screen font sizes (as seen [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Make-the-text-on-your-screen-larger-or-smaller)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can copy the ellipsis character (…) from this post, or use Alt-0133 to produce it on demand.

```
Button.Text = "…";
```

> The button is still much larger than I'd like...

Adjust the font size?

> ...and the dots don't stand out very well.

Make the font bold? (**…**)

I suppose if none of this works for you, an image is the next-best thing.

Comment: The ellipses character did make it look a lot better.  23x23 seems to be about the right size as well.  I found that if I used FlatStyle=System property, it would allow me to make it much smaller as it removes all of the whitespace beside the ellipses character... but that's too small for the page.

Answer (score 4):

1. Use some image with dots.
2. ☼☼☼  Use Character Map of Windows to find dots you need and cope/past them into the Text property.

Sample: ···

Comment: +１ for the sample. It looks better than the ellipsis character.

Answer (score 2):

This is what we use: `Button.Text = "..."`.

If it is too big, you can adjust the font size down.

Answer (score 1):

Set the button's Text to '...' and change its Size property. You can also change the Button's Font, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to make it look nice in WPF (Using .NET 5)

**Code:**

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="34" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Directory" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ImagesDirectory}"
           VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
           Height="24" />
  <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="&#x26AB;&#x26AB;&#x26AB;"
          FontSize="4" Margin="-1,5,5,5" Height="24" />
<Grid>
```

**Preview:**

[image: Button With Ellipses using Bullets in WPF]